# catching wrong url for server error

Tags: python, couchdb

if I initialise a server but use the wrong url my script locks up without giving a useful error.

```
url = sys.argv[1]
couch = couchdb.Server(url)
print type(couch)           # returns couchdb.client.Server even if url is wrong

print type(couch.stats())   # locks up before it can print
```

is there anything I can use to test that it's a valid server.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `version()` instead. [From the docs](https://pythonhosted.org/CouchDB/client.html#server):

> version() The version string of the CouchDB server.
>
> Note that this results in a request being made, **and can also be used
>   to check for the availability of the server**.

So use `couch.version()` instead of `couch.stats()`

Comment: same issue unfortunately.